# How do I use the Facebook Graph API to like a comment?

Tags: facebook, c#-4.0, facebook-graph-api

How do I "like" a comment using the Facebook Graph API in C#?

Comment: What do the docs say to do? [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Facebook comment docs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/Comment/):

> You can like a comment by issuing an HTTP POST request to COMMENT_ID/likes with the publish_stream permission. No parameters necessary.

Also, check out the [Facebook C# library](https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk).